# I want to put forms in an array but this isnt going well

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, forms

I want to turn a few forms off at the same time.
When I run it, it still shows all the forms when I select 'case 1'.
The meaning of this all is to select 'how much trackbars' he want to see. by default it is 10, and it depends how much he select. lets say he select 6. so i put trackbar 7-10 on false, same by as textboxes and pictureboxes.
Sorry for my bad english, i hope you all understand my question, thanks for reading!

```
namespace project
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(int sliders)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string[,] test = new string[10, 4]   {{"trackBar1.visible = false;", "textbox1,visible = false;", "textbox11.visible = false;", "picturebox2.visisble = false;"},
                    {"trackBar2.visible = false;", "textbox2,visible = false;", "textbox12.visible = false;", "picturebox3.visisble = false;"},
                    {"trackBar3.visible = false;", "textbox3,visible = false;", "textbox13.visible = false;", "picturebox4.visisble = false;"},
                    {"trackBar4.visible = false;", "textbox4,visible = false;", "textbox14.visible = false;", "picturebox5.visisble = false;"},
                    {"trackBar5.visible = false;", "textbox5,visible = false;", "textbox15.visible = false;", "picturebox6.visisble = false;"},
                    {"trackBar6.visible = false;", "textbox6,visible = false;", "textbox16.visible = false;", "picturebox7.visisble = false;"},
                    {"trackBar7.visible = false;", "textbox7,visible = false;", "textbox17.visible = false;", "picturebox8.visisble = false;"},
                    {"trackBar8.visible = false;", "textbox8,visible = false;", "textbox18.visible = false;", "picturebox9.visisble = false;"},
                    {"trackBar9.visible = false;", "textbox9,visible = false;", "textbox19.visible = false;", "picturebox10.visisble = false;"},
                    {"trackBar10.visible = false;", "textbox10,visible = false;", "textbox20.visible = false;", "picturebox11.visisble = false;"}};
        switch (sliders)
        {

            case 1:

                foreach (string item in test)
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                    Console.ReadLine();
break;
} 
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of trackbar or textbox controls and iterate over them to set visibility.  Otherwise you'll have to use reflection to get control from string.

I'd recommend not to use strings and better to use typed collections.